# Implementing "best match" for sound effects

Tags: audio, effects, matching, closest

I am looking for some advice on categorizing a library of sound effects. I have a large set of random sound effects, (think whistles, pops, growls, creaks, gunshots etc). I would like to be able to take a growl for example, and find the next growl that sounds the closest to the original.

Given a sound, what sound from my set sounds the closest to it.

I have done a fair amount of googling and have found two avenues that I am still researching. One is using echonest, although their "best match" support looks not promising for public users. The other option is diving into FFT and building my own matching algorithm. This is a fine option and would be a great learning experience but I wanted to get some opinions from others who might know a little more about sound processing; especially short clips .5sec - 3sec range, not full length music.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in movie postproduction for years and as far as I know, there is no way to do that automatically. Every file has meta information in its file header which describes what the sound is like. You are then actually not searching for the file names but in the meta string.

I don't think that it is trivial to sort effects programmatically as two effects that sound similar might be totally different if you look at the waveform.
You would need to extract significant information about a sound that you can then compare.
I am also not a DSP expert, maybe there are methods to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in trying to build your own system to do this, I can suggest a few keywords that might help to refine your Google searches.  In the academic research community, the task you're describing is often called "content-based audio searching". I know there's been a lot of work done on it, and though most pertains to music, sound effects have definitely been the focus of a number of studies.

You might want to start with [the work of Pedro Cano](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.75.738).

Also, I recently heard about a company that's doing similar work.  You might want to check out products from [Imagine Research](http://imagine-research.com/mediamined-technology).

Those are just a couple of ideas off the top of my head. I'm not %100 sure they'll be helpful.  If they are, please let me know!